# Is the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ a vector space relative to positive numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, real-numbers

Let the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ be the positive real numbers along with 0.

This set is not a vector space relative to $\mathbb{R}$ (real numbers) because multiplying an element of the first quadrant by a negative number lands outside of the first quadrant, thus breaking a condition to be a vector space.

However, could we define the first quadrant as a vector space relative to only a subset of the real numbers, e.g. positive ones + 0?

Comment: Where do inverses live?

Comment: @Randall, forgot about that. Indeed, the inverses are outside my failed vector space so it is not a vector space. I was trying to look for an example of a set of vectors that are not a vector space relative to a set of scalars but become a vector space with another set of scalars but I failed with this example. If you transform your comment into a more elaborate answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This structure is not called a vector space because the positive real numbers are not a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), since they don't have an additive identity or inverses.

However, the nonnegative reals do form a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) (like a ring but without additive inverses), and the nonnegative first quadrant $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x, y \ge 0 \}$ is a [semimodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimodule) over it. This is still pretty good; note that vector spaces are precisely modules over fields, and the semiring $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ still behaves like a field in that every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse (so it is a [semifield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semifield)).

Comment: Can we talk about norms on such a structure?  So far norms are defined on vector space if I am not wrong…

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to stress here that this is a convex cone.
A subset $K$ is a convex cone if it is closed under addition and multiplication with nonnegative real numbers.